# Loading bar http request with interval

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to hook into a stream a) before the request is executed and b) after the request is received (e.g. to show/hide a loading bar). Without using **interval** I could set a boolean isLoaded to false and set it to true in the subscribe function.

But how can I do that with using interval?

```
Observable.interval(5000).
        timeout(3500, new Error('Server not available.')).
        flatMap(() => this._http.get('http://api.dev/get/events')).
        map(res => (<Response>res).json())
        .subscribe(data => this.events = data,
                   error => console.debug('ERROR', error),
                   () => console.log('END')
        );
```

Do I have to wrap angulars http.get method in my own observable? Or is there a better / "more angular" way to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation of [Angular Loading Bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar)?

Comment: Yes, I have. But that is angular1 and I'm using angular2.

Comment: Dang, sorry...totally spaced on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not use interval because network request can delay and take longer/shorter times then the interval which would/could make it inconsistent. The way to do it though is...

```
// the import needed is
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

private intervalSub: Subscription;
private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject();

 somefunction (){
    // Interval_Time was 5000
     this.intervalSub = interval(Interval_Time)
     .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(() => {
                // call your api and do the request every Interval time
     }
   }

// make sure you have 
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

the reason you need the ngUnsubscribe subject is so if you route away from the component then it won't keep polling.